# How to verify given string is valid JsonArray using a net.sf.json library

Tags: java, json, arrays

I am using `net.sf.json` library for `json To java` and vice-versa conversion

i have a following string:

```
String jsonStr = "{\"name\" : \"abc\",\"address\"  : \"def\"}";    // line 1
```

I tried to verify above string as valid json array using below code :

```
JSONArray arr = JSONArray.fromObject(jsonStr);      // line 2
System.out.println(arr.isArray());       // line 3
```

But i get the following ***exception at line 2***

```
Exception in thread "main" net.sf.json.JSONException: A JSONArray text must start with '[' at character 1 of {"name" : "abc","address"  : "def"}
    at net.sf.json.util.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:527)
    at net.sf.json.JSONArray._fromJSONTokener(JSONArray.java:1146)
    at net.sf.json.JSONArray._fromString(JSONArray.java:1226)
    at net.sf.json.JSONArray.fromObject(JSONArray.java:151)
    at net.sf.json.JSONArray.fromObject(JSONArray.java:129)
    at com.example.WsClient.main(WsClient.java:2) //
```

Now there is no static method in `JSONArray` class to verify it as valid json string, so i have to create a json array and then verify it. But i am getting the exception while creating the array.
Then how can i use this method ?

**How can i verify that above string is a `valid json Array` ?**

**EDIT :** Currently the string is an object but if i create a method with String as argument to convert to a jsonArray. How can i verify the string as valid json array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `net.sf.json.JSONArray.fromObject()` docu:

> Throws: `JSONException` - if the object can not be converted to a proper
>   `JSONArray`.

So you already validated your string via exception, and you know this is not a JSON valid array string. If you get this JSON string as method argument you could re-throw the exception (by your method), or handle locally (by returning `null`).

`isArray()` method is part of the Interface `JSON` which is implemented by `JSONArray`.

> `boolean  isArray()` 
>             Returns `true` if this object is a `JSONArray`, `false` otherwise.

I am expecting you can call this later if you have actually valid parsed JSON array and if your object is `JSONArray`.

What I am trying to say you don't need special check if this string is valid. You have two solutions:

```
public XXX parseYourString(String json) throws net.sf.json.JSONException {
    JSONArray arr = JSONArray.fromObject(json);
    // do something with arr and return custom result
}
```

or:

```
public XXX parseYourString(String json) {
    XXX xxx = new XXX();
    try {
          JSONArray arr = JSONArray.fromObject(json);

          // do something with arr

    } catch (JSONException ex) {
        return null;
    }
    return xxx;
}
```

Comment: though you are right but only when i know string is valid array, what if get that string as method arguement.please see my edit

Comment: edited. You just need to handle this exception and make some decision to return null, or throw exception by your method (and handle later).

Comment: that solution is provided by @Ankur Lathi.
I am looking for solution using this API rather than making decision on basis of exception.Though i think so it is the only approach left.

Comment: You don't really need to make special check if this is valid string because you receive this information from exception.

Answer (score 1):

You can check it like this:

```
public boolean isValid(String jsonString)
{
    boolean valid = false;
    try {
        JSONArray.fromObject(jsonString)
        valid = true;
    }
    catch(JSONException ex) { 
        valid = false;
    }
    return valid;
}
```